# Ajax URL Request to Long

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a fairly standard Ajax function to call my controller passing up an array of ID's. I believe the problem is to do with the URL that is constructed being over 2000 characters.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DistributionRule/GetCalculatedResults/",
        data: {
            'ProfileItemIDs': JSON.parse(localStorage['filteredStores']), // Array of Intergers
        },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true, // Perform a traditional "shallow" serialization.
        success: function (data) {
             // To Do
        },
        error: function () {
             // To Do
        }
    });
```

If I just pass a small array it works absolutely fine its when i'm sending an array bigger than 300 integers.

Typically this array could vary between 1 .. n, what is the best way to overcome this issue I am faced with?

---

**EDIT** - Server-side code

***Controller***

```
public JsonResult GetCalculatedResults(ProductCalculatorVM vm)
{
    // To Do
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

***View Model***

```
public class ProductCalculatorVM
{
    public int[] ProfileItemIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: instead of GET try to POST

Comment: Unfortunately when changing from `GET` to `POST` both serverside and clientside, my controller doesn't get called instead it throws `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: in this way you need to use loop for bigger data

Comment: @JohnCooling just swapping GET to POST won't suffice. You'll therefore have to implement a new POST action in your controller.

Comment: @khlr if you re-read my comment above you will see that I have updated my code both server-side and client-side for `POST`

Comment: Could you please post your server side code?

Comment: @NileshThakkar please see my edit

Comment: Did you try configuring both the methods as POST?

Comment: I did yes, when it was a `POST` method it wouldn't get hit so I couldn't debug it

Comment: @JohnCooling: Changing to POST is defintiely the way to solve your problem with url length. Your followup problem needs debugging separately. ie the cause of your 500 error is somethign you need to look into. You might also want to check that your controller action doesn't have attributes telling it that it must be called via HttpGet.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to increase the size of a parameter in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```